# Invalid JWT token

Tags: jwt, postman, mern, bearer-token

I am currently working with/learning about Json Web tokens and learning how to implement protected routes in a future application since I am following the "Learn Mern Stack" youtube video. I am using Postman, when I create a new for my application, it creates a token as well, when I log in as that said user my code still works and I come up with that same token, but when i try to enter that token as a Bearer token it comes up with an error. What I have found out is:

- my token for some reason is not getting verified causing the 401 "Not authorized" error.
- When I enter my token into JWT.io I keep getting the Error "invalid signature" and it comes up with the warning error saying "Warning: looks like your JWT signature is not encoded correctly using base64url"
  -After doing some reasearch I tried to enter base64.RawURLEncoding and other attempts like it into my code but my token still comes up as unauthorized.
- The token is written correctly, separated correctly and no "=" signs and it is not expired.
  Here are some pics and pieces of my code, would anyone be able to give me a hint of why this is happening?

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const {
  registerUser,
  loginUser,
  getMe,
} = require("../controllers/userController.js");
const { protect } = require("../middleware/authMiddleware.js");

router.post("/", registerUser);
router.post("/login", loginUser);
router.get("/me", protect, getMe);

module.exports = router;
```

```css
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const User = require("../models/userModel");

const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;

  if (
    base64.RawURLEncoding.req.headers.authorization &&
    base64.RawURLEncoding.req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")
  ) {
    try {
      // Get token from header
      token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];

      // Verify token
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

      // Get user from the token
      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select("-password");

      next();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(401);
      throw new Error("Not authorized");
    }
  }

  if (!token) {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("Not authorized, no token");
  }
});

module.exports = { protect };
```

```html
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const User = require("../models/userModel");

// @desc    Register new user
// @route   POST /api/users
// @access  Public
const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;

  if (!name || !email || !password) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Please add all fields");
  }

  // Check if user exists
  const userExists = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (userExists) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("User already exists");
  }

  // Hash password
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

  // Create user
  const user = await User.create({
    name,
    email,
    password: hashedPassword,
  });

  if (user) {
    res.status(201).json({
      _id: user.id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    });
  } else {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Invalid user data");
  }
});

// @desc    Authenticate a user
// @route   POST /api/users/login
// @access  Public
const loginUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  // Check for user email
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
    res.json({
      _id: user.id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    });
  } else {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
  }
});

// @desc    Get user data
// @route   GET /api/users/me
// @access  Private
const getMe = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json(req.user);
});

// Generate JWT
const generateToken = (id) => {
  return jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "30d",
  });
};

module.exports = {
  registerUser,
  loginUser,
  getMe,
};
```

[image]

Creating a user
[image: logging in as that user]

[image: finding created user through token_id]

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code is getting the toke:

```js
token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]; // from 'req.headers.authorization'
```

but from the images it seems like you are passing the token as field in the body of the request, therefore it cannot be found in `req.headers.authorization`.

you have to put it there instead:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

bro as far as I understand from your screenshots and question , I think your are trying to do the following things

1. create a user using **api/users** Post endpoint
2. Login using **/api/users/login** Post endpoint. - which also gets you the JWT Token in the response.
3. Trying to fetch user details via **api/users/me** Get Endpoint - This gives you No Authorization error.

I guess you are not sending the Authorization header in that request (**api/users/me**) as i don't see any green check on that request(refer your screenshot of that req). So you have to set that token as Basic auth header. follow the screenshot provided by [Ahmed Sbai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76905882/1445295) in the above answer. if you want it to be set automatically then go to **Test Tab** of **/api/users/login** request and save your token either in collection variables or env variables.

```js
    var login_response=pm.response.json();
    pm.collectionVariables.set("jwt-token",login_response.token);
```

Now use this variable **jwt-token** as a Authorization token in any request which requires token . refer below SS.

[image: autorization postman screenshot]